# Plot f1 for a specific class with sklearn's learning_curve() rather than the weighted f1 scores

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

When plotting a learning curve with `sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve()` on a boolean supervised classifier, it defaults to displaying the weighted f1 score.

But I'd like to plot the f1 score for a specific class. In this case the positive (aka: 1) class.

In the context of below (from `sklearn.metrics.classification_report`), its plotting `avg / total`, but I would like to plot metrics for the class `1`.

[image]

**Plot**

[image]

**Code**

```
...
estimator = classifier_class()
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X_recombined, y_recombined, cv=cv) # n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes

train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
plt.grid()

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, 
                 train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, 
                 alpha=0.1, color="r")

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, 
                 test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, 
                 alpha=0.1, color="g")

plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r", label="Training score")

plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g", label="Cross-validation score")

plt.legend(loc="best")
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

### For a binary classification

You can set a custom scorer to `learning_curve` using the `scoring` param. From doc:

> **scoring : string, callable or None, optional, default: None**
>
> A string (see model evaluation documentation) or a scorer callable object / function with signature scorer(estimator, X, y).

Also, `sklearn.metrics.f1_score` function doc say:

> **pos_label : str or int, 1 by default**
>
> The class to report if
>   average='binary' and the data is binary. If the data are multiclass or
>   multilabel, this will be ignored; setting labels=[pos_label] and
>   average != 'binary' will report scores for that label only.
>
> **average : string, [None, ‘binary’ (default), ‘micro’, ‘macro’,
>   ‘samples’, ‘weighted’]**
>
> This parameter is required for
>   multiclass/multilabel targets. If None, the scores for each class are
>   returned. Otherwise, this determines the type of averaging performed
>   on the data:
>
> `'binary'`: Only report results for the class specified by pos_label.
>   This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.

Thus, you can do this:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, make_scorer

# Custom scorer
target = 0 # class you want to plot
scorer = make_scorer(lambda y_true, y_pred: f1_score(
    y_true, y_pred, 
    labels=None, 
    pos_label=target, 
    average='binary', 
    sample_weight=None))

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator, 
    X, 
    y, 
    cv=cv,
    scoring=scorer)
```