# How do I correct the continuous error given when trying to train a model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, predict

I wrote this code and it is giving me the error 'continuous', can someone help me?

```
#Training and testing the models
print ('LogisticRegression')


clf_LR = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial',max_iter=2000)
clf_LR.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred= clf_LR.predict(X_test)

lg_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
f1=f1_score(y_test,pred,average = 'micro')
print ('LogisticRegression Accuracy:{}'.format(lg_acc))
print ('F1 Score:{}'.format(f1) )
```

I changed from SVC to SVR and do not know what part I should change ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try [learning_curve()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-learning-curve-py)  like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622067/plot-f1-for-a-specific-class-with-sklearns-learning-curve-rather-than-the-wei)?